# Swift 3 JSON get String from JSONArray does not work

Tags: ios, json, string, object, swift3

I try to extract the value of filename from my JSON server response.

```
if let attachments = itemDict["attachments"] as? [[String:String]] {
            for attachment in attachments {
               print(attachment["filename"])
            }
        }
```

And here is my JSON String.

```
"attachments":[{"filename":"000000_none-5.png","uploadDate":1482062835000,"imageRatio":0.0}
,{"filename":"000000_none-2.png","uploadDate":1482062839000,"imageRatio":0.0}]
```

and it does not work. What am I doing wrong, i seriously do not know. It does not go into the for loop.

Thanks for any helpful response in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries are not `[String:String]` they are `[String:Any]` since they contain also `Int` and `Double` values:

```
if let attachments = itemDict["attachments"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    for attachment in attachments {
       print(attachment["filename"] as! String)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to cast as `[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]` instead of `[[String:String]]`